# Add Recurrence event on outlook 2010 from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, calendar

I have my friends date of birth in excel with name and dob column. I have to import the birthday events in my outlook calender with reminder of every year.

I tried with birth date as start date and remainder date. Can't able to set recurrence.

Any one can help me to achieve the recurrence event from excel to outlook?

Comment: Looks like an old post... but does it have to be a vba... because direct import is also possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your code looks, but I found [a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869162.aspx) on MSDN which works for me (Outlook 2010). The following code creates a new appointment and sets the recurrence to every two years:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateTestAppt()
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim oPattern As RecurrencePattern

    Set oAppt = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    Set oPattern = oAppt.GetRecurrencePattern
    With oPattern
        ' Appointment occurs every n-th year (with n indicated by the Interval property)
        .RecurrenceType = olRecursYearNth
        ' Appointment recurs every 2 years (per a RecurrenceType of olRecursYearNth)
        .Interval = 2
    End With
    oAppt.Subject = "Test appointment"
    oAppt.Save
    oAppt.Display

    Set oPattern = Nothing
    Set oAppt = Nothing
End Sub
```